# New relator in hurwitz group

Tags: gr.group-theory

I have found that $([a,b]^2[a,b^2])^n$ is a good relator to use in my search for quotients of $G := \langle a, b \ | \ a^2, b^3, (ab)^7, [a,b]^{10} \rangle$. For n<=5 $H := \langle a, b \ | \ a^2, b^3, (ab)^7, [a,b]^{10}, ([a,b]^2[a,b^2])^n \rangle$ is the trivial group, but when n=6, it is the Janko group J1, and when n=7, it is the Hall-Janko group J2. I have tried finding what the group is when n = 8, but without success (magma failed, and GAP used too much memory and crashed my computer). Is there a way of finding what this group is?

Comment: At first sight, it looks like $H=G$.

Comment: That can't be possible, because the order of $([a,b]^2[a,b^2])$ is not 8 (otherwise when n=6 the group would be trivial). Also, the Janko group J1 is a quotient of G, but not of H (when n=8), since the Janko group contains no elements of order 8.

Comment: Woops, sorry, I made an error in the question. Corrected now.

Comment: I suppose you know already that $G$ maps onto ${\rm PSL}_2({\bf F}_{41})$.  (The exponent of $\ [a,b]^2[a,b^2]$ in the image is $21$.)

Comment: Yes, so far I know that G maps onto PSL2(F41), J1, J2, and also some of the Chevalley groups G2. G2(5) is the smallest Chevalley group, and the exponent for that is 31. Also, I know that J1 is also a quotient of H for n=10.

Comment: Have you tried computing the abelianization of low-index subgroups? If you get lucky, you might show that it's infinite this way. (Note: it's a fact that this works for sufficiently large n, so this strategy is hopeful.)

Comment: There is a subgroup of index two, but the abelianization is the trivial group. Also, the abelianization of the original group H is trivial. Wait, this is interesting... the subgroup has the same presentation (by Tietze transforms) as H. What does this mean?

Comment: Well, if that's true then it certainly implies that your group is infinite (since no finite group is isomorphic to a proper subgroup of itself).

Comment: I used the LowIndexSubgroups method. Would it be possible for the group to be trivial, and for GAP to just not have figured out that its trivial?

Comment: Thomas - there's something wrong with what you said above.  If H has a subgroup of index two then the abelianization of H is not trivial (since H maps onto Z/2).

Comment: And, now I think about it, the abelianization of G, hence H, is certainly trivial. Perhaps you got 'all subgroups of index *at most* 2'?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. It wasn't index 2 at all, it was index 1.

Comment: I've found that none of the groups PSL(2, 41), J1, J2, G2(5) are quotients of H (when n=8). Either this group is trivial, or it has some quotients we haven't discovered yet. If I recall correctly, it has been checked that there are no other quotients of G (and therefore H) of order less than 2,000,000,000.

Comment: It would be possible for $H$ to have no nontrivial finite quotients but still be infinite.

Comment: It would be quite an interesting group if that was true. It (or at least one of its quotients) would be an infinite, finitely presented simple group. How could that be proven though?

Comment: @Thomas, no , it would be a so-called *almost simple* group.  These are rather easier to construct than infinite simple groups.

Answer (score 8):

A brute-force calculation in GAP (searching for homomorphisms) shows that the group G has a quotient $PSL_2(41)\times J1^2\times J2^2\times G_2(5)^2$.
There are no other quotients that are simple groups of order $\le 10^{10}$, and (as you surely know) the group is perfect.

The order of $[a,b]^2[a,b^2]$ under the simple quotients is 21 (PSL), 6 and 10 (J1), 7 and 15 (J2) and both times 31 (G2(5)). Thus this gives you information for $n=10$, but not $n=8$.

Its only $PSL_2$ quotient is $PSL_2(41)$. (Noam Elkies mentioned this already, but the statement might not have been clear about that there are no others) , this is by the Plesken/Fabianska algorithm in Magma.

Comment: Are those the highest powers of each of those simple groups that are quotients of G? It was found (in another question) that G2(3^4), G2(7^2), G2(11^2), G2(13^4) are also quotients of G (and there should be more quotients corresponding to higher primes). Is it possible to figure out the highest power of each of those that are quotients of G, and the exponent of $[a,b]^2[a,b^2]$ for each?

Comment: I had noticed that the simple quotients were there for different exponents. Does that always imply that there are multiple powers of the group appearing as a quotient?

Comment: Yes, there are two (independent) copies each of J1, J2 and G2(5).

Comment: and I should have said only two -- assuming my program is correct it found all normal subgroups such that $G/N$ is of the given isomorphism type.

Comment: Yes it is possible to compute the order of that element in the image of $G$ in $G_2(p^e)$ (where $e=1,2$ or $4$) for any prime $p$. The $7$-dimensional representation over a number field of degree $7$ over the rationals was computed explicitly by Plesken and Robertz, so you just have to reduce the matrices modulo $p$. I tried this for primes up to about $10000$, but the smallest orders I found were $30$, $31$, $108$,...

Comment: Sorry,the number field has degree $4$ over the rationals, not $7$.

Comment: Does each G2(p^e) appear twice in G? Also, for which p did you find order 30?